# conda env create failed?

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to create a new environment for anaconda installation that I want to tweak apart from the original install. I found this not working:

```
$ conda env create --name pandas018numpy111 pandas018test1
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Error: Invalid name, try the format: user/package
pandas018test1 does not exist or can't be accessed
environment.yml file not found
There is no requirements.txt
```

What is wrong here?

What I wanted to accomplish was to create the copy of the original environment, add some modules for testing around, then toss away the test environment (pandas018numpy111).

Comment: `conda env create --name pandas018numpy111 pandas018test1` what is `pandas018test1` doing here? Can you explain a little bit what this command is supposed to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer.

What I need is the `conda create` command, actually,

```
$ conda create -n pandas018numpy111 --clone root
```

Then I have the throw-away environment to modify, etc and later just toss. To switch then I will just use:

```
$ source activate pandas018numpy111
```

and to exit from this environment,

```
$ source deactivate
```

Comment: The conda API is unfortunately weirdly inconsistent... It's `conda env create -f ` to create an environment from a file, but `conda create -n` to create it with a name...